# Jplayer - Creating dynamic play list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer

I am using jPLayer to play mp3's for a project.  They mp3's will be loaded dynamically from a database.  I am trying to create the links that will load the selected mp3 into the player.  Currently I have which does does not work.  I believe I am doing something incorrectly with the click event telling what mp3 to play.  If I hardcode the path it works fine but I do not want to set it up that way because there could be hundreds of media files.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
         ready: function () {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            mp3: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-07-Bubble.mp3"
        }).jPlayer("play");
         },
         ended: function (event) {
        $(this).jPlayer("play");
         },
         swfPath: "js",
         supplied: "mp3"
    });

       $(".song").click(function() {
       $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("setMedia", {
        mp3: $(this).attr("name").val();
       });
        $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("play");
    return false;
    });

});
```

```
        <a href="#" class="song" name="http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-07-Bubble.mp3">Song 3</a>
        <a href="#" class="song" name="http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-04-Lismore.mp3">Song 4</a>
```

This code does work but I would like to get the info from the href

```
$(".song").click(function() {
        $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("setMedia", {
            mp3: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-04-Lismore.mp3"
        });
        $("#jp_playlist_1 ul").html("Lismore - MP3");
        $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("play");
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing this `$(this).attr("name").val();` with `$(this).attr("name");`

also a good idea would be:

```
<a  class="song" href="http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-07-Bubble.mp3">Song 3</a>
```

and then

```
$('.song').click(function(eve){
eve.preventDefault();
...
...
...

});
```

and of course

```
mp3: $(this).attr("href")
```

Comment: hmm tried making those changes and setting it to the href and adding the preventDefault but it is still opening the link normally.  edit-  Actually the preventDefault(); is working it's just that the javascript in general isn't working when I have that code inserted for the mp3

Comment: loose the ; in the end of the $(this).attr('href')

Comment: That was it.  Thank's a ton.  I really appreciate it.  I had a feeling I was doing something small